# Deregister only Classic Editor styles (but leave Guten css)

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'd like to keep the Guten styles, what do I do to only remove classic editor tinymce styles?

Using function
  `wp_deregister_style('wp-reset-editor-styles');`
to disable default WP css on TinyMCE to style it with a skin, but it's also destroying Guten builder.

Answer (score 0):

To remove your editor style, simply find where it's enqueued in your theme (probably using `add_editor_style`) and then you can add it back in for the block editor, using the action below.

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_enqueue_block_editor_assets', 102);
function my_enqueue_block_editor_assets () {
wp_register_style( 'wp-reset-editor-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheets/my-custom-stylesheet.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
}
```